# Динамические графики в Python

Tags: python, анимация, matplotlib

Добрый день!

Хотелось бы получить подсказку, или, возможно, верный алгоритм построения динамических графиков, может быть, в matplotlib, может, ещё с помощью чего-нибудь. Хочу чтобы график выводился в окне (сохранение в `.png` уже победил), и в этом же окне перестраивался. Загвоздка в том, что выводить мне необходимо данные из 2D ndarray, которые обновляются в цикле. Если запустить `plt.show()` в самом цикле, то цикл дальше не идёт, пока не закрыть окно с текущим графиком, закрываю — цикл идёт дальше, и отрисовывается новое окно, и ничего не меняется, пока не закроешь его. Если запустить до цикла, то код не идёт дальше `show()` (пока его не закроешь). И аналогичный вопрос с 3D графиком. В программе моделирую гидродинамику, хотелось бы визуально это всё видеть.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/animation/index.html

Comment: Посмотрите библиотеку http://www.pyqtgraph.org/, в ней можно выводить все типы графиков, включая 3D поверхности. И работает значительно быстрее чем `matplotlib`.